# Relationship between logical and analytic completeness?

Tags: logic

A complete metric space is one where every cauchy sequence converges, and a complete logical system has all tautologies theorems.

There's nothing immediate to me about their relationship other than the word "completeness," which may have just been chosen for both properties because of its English meaning, but I was curious if there was anything relating them.

In particular, I have only done work with languages that have countable alphabets (hence countably many formulae). Are there uncountable alphabets with uncountable formulae where a sequence of deducible tautologies "approaching" a formula which is provable iff the set is complete?

Comment: Completeness roughly means that you can't expand the structure in a meaningful way without losing something. In the case of logic, that means that any new axiom added is either redundant or makes the system inconsistent. In the analytic case, there are no new numbers that can be added without losing some of the nice properties of the reals.

Comment: I would rather say that *in*completeness is the power to extend the structure so that it keeps its properties but acquires new elements. The incomplete logical system can be extended by adding a tautology that is not a theorem. The incomplete metric space can be extended by adding *those non-converging Cauchy sequences* as new elements (with suitable identification of those sequences that eventually end up converging to the same value). E.g. you "add" $\sqrt{2}$ to $\mathbb Q$ as "any Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb Q$ which diverges in $\mathbb Q$ but converges to $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb R$".

Comment: What do you mean by a "tautology"? Usually, all tautologies are theorems, in *any* logical system. A complete system is one in which every sentence is either provable or disprovable (i.e., either that sentence is a theorem, or its negation is a theorem).